# Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox can ssh to VPN server under WinXP host, but not Win7 host after import

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, vpn

I just did a fresh install of the latest version of VBox (4.3.20) on my brand-spankin' new Windows 7 64-bit machine, then imported the vdi file describing my Ubuntu guest installation (14.04 32-bit) and settings from my WinXP 32-bit machine. Everything seemed to work okay until I try to ssh into a server (let's call it network-alias) on my VPN:

```
$ ssh myusername@network-alias
ssh: Could not resolve hostname network-alias: Name or service not known
```

I'm confused; this worked as expected on my XP machine. I'd simply fire up the Juniper VPN connect, then VBox, and could SSH. I can connect to the VPN on my Win7 machine (which itself can also see `http://network-alias/`), then fire up VBox as admin, but now ssh isn't working, giving the above error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may just be a DNS failure. 
See if you can get any lookups to succeed.

```
dig yahoo.com
```

'A' record(s) returned? No, try looking up against a specific DNS server instead (in this example a public DNS server):

```
dig @8.8.8.8 yahoo.com
```

Any better luck?

If neither works then DNS queries are not making it out at all. If only the second one works, check to see what nameservers the guest is configured to use for DNS (defined within /etc/resolv.conf) and update as necessary.

You can also check if the host (Win 7) system is able to make DNS lookups (although you would know right away as all your browsing would be failing right?). If the host is working but the guest is not then something is affecting the requests from the guest (perhaps a windows firewall issue... network security app... other blocking configuration/application) making it out.

If all the DNS is working properly... then more info is needed :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: DNS lookup is working fine from the guest, and browsing working fine from the host (I'm currently sending this over the VPN). VBox is being run as admin and full Windows Firewall permissions have been granted to it. The really strange thing is that even though my guest can apparently make successful DNS queries, it has full packet loss from pinging sites like Google and Yahoo and cannot ssh. This is mystifying me.

Comment: Ended up just installing cygwin with ssh and used that. Doesn't fix the problem exactly, but it gives me the functionality I need.